# Prevent awk from removing "\" (backslashes) in variable

Tags: bash, awk, quoting, variable

I have this line of code for the shell:

```
ls -1 *.mp3| awk -v here="$(cygpath -w $PWD)" -v source="$source" '{print "File Name: "$0"\n"here"\n"source}'
```

Unfortunately it outputs:

```
File Name: Data 00053.mp3
C:UsersathenaWorkProject_10.MBT
Source: Converted from RAW
```

This line `C:UsersathenaWorkProject_10.MBT`
Should be `C:\Users\athena\Work\Project_10\00.MBT`

I am now lost, a lot to learn here.

Comment: See also `cygpath -aw .` for the current working directory in Windows format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's an issue relating to how `awk` treats the value passed using `-v`.  It interprets the backslashes in the passed string.

Instead, pass it through an environment variable:

```
here="$(cygpath -w "$PWD")" awk ... '{ print ... ENVIRON["here"] ... }'
```

`ENVIRON` is an associative array in `awk` that contains the values of the variables in the current environment, keyed by name.

Also related to your code:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Comment: It solved the issue for sure.

Comment: It doesn't work for multiple variables though. Any thoughts?

Comment: @KenIngram Did you try? `a=1 b=2 c=3 awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["a"], ENVIRON["b"], ENVIRON["c"] }'`. You could obviously just `export` the variables instead of assigning them on the same command line as `awk` (but that would make them part of your script's environment too).